# Grouping values in Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2014

Please consider this simple table:

```
declare @tbl  Table
(
    Id          int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Year]      int,
    [Month]     tinyint,
    [Value]     int
);

insert into @tbl VALUES
    (2010, 1, 2000),
    (2010, 2, 500),
    (2011, 4, 8000),
    (2011, 1, 800),
    (2010, 1, 5000),
    (2011, 5, 1000),
    (2010, 8, 7000),
    (2011, 3, 7000),
    (2010, 1, 4000),
    (2011, 1, 900),
    (2011, 1, 9000)
```

I want to group these record by `Year` and `Month` but in the result I want a number for every year indicate every 3-months period:

```
1             First 3-Months period
2             Second 3-Months period
3             third 3-Months period
4             Fourth 3-Months period
```

and my desired result is :

```
Year        Period              Sum Of Values
---------------------------------------------
2010          1                     11500
2010          3                     7000
2011          1                     17700
2011          2                     9000
```

How can I get this result? Thanks

Comment: you can create the 'periods' table and do a non equi join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0138ee/1/0

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks but I don't want create(or declare) another table...

Comment: I understand. You know you don't need to persist it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/968ea4/2/0. Here with your case, but I prefer the other solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/968ea4/5/0

Comment: @daniherrera Great. Why you didn't add these fiddles as answer?

Comment: Bé free to post your own solution with fiddles code. Maybe this can help other users. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the period/quarter using `(month+2)/3`:

```
select year, (month+2) / 3 as quarter, sum(value)
from @tbl
group by year, (month+2) / 3
order by 1,2
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9c247ff41e9caea29c68c674a8a2f771)

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use `Case`? for example if I want to return result for other periods for example 6-months 9 months or...

Comment: Of course, `case when month <=3 then 1 when month <=6 then 2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the period by taking the `ceiling` of the month divided by 3.0. You need to use 3.0 rather than 3 as otherwise SQL Server will calculate the results of the division as an integer (which will be the floored result).

```
select year, ceiling(month/3.0)  , sum(value) from @tbl
group by year, ceiling(month/3.0) 
order by 1,2
```

If you need to change what the period was, you just need to change the denominator of your division, e.g a 6 month period would be done with

```
select year, ceiling(month/6.0)  , sum(value) from @tbl
group by year, ceiling(month/6.0) 
order by 1,2
```

Here's a fiddle which demonstrates this including the integer division problem https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c107c98928d262330513c2f33484366